# Loop two variables through one command in shell

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I want to run a shell script that can simultaneously loop through two variables.
So that I can have an input and output file name. I feel like this isn't too hard of a concept but any help is appreciated.

```
Files = "File1,
         File2,
         ...
         FileN
         "

Output = OutFile1,
         Outfile2,
         ...
         OutfileN
         "
```

and I would in theory my code would be:

```
for File in $Files
do
    COMMAND --file $File --ouput $Output        
done
```

Obviously, there needs to be another loop but I'm stuck, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do the names of the input and output files map as simply as input1 -> output1 in reality?

Comment: I'm confused on the question. I want the input file to be simply renamed to an output file name. Let's say the file name is written in a non-human-readable format such as ACCTA-CJA1234.fastq.gz, I want the output file to be something human readable such as Patient_101_Alignment.

Comment: I mean is there a simple relationship between the names of the input files and the output files? In your question, it looks like all your files have the same name with a different number on the end. What does your real list of input and output file names look like?

Comment: Don't worry about it @anubhava told me how to do to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need to loop 2 variables, just use 2 BASH arrays:

```
input=("File1" "File2" "File3")
output=("OutFile1" "OutFile2" "OutFile3")

for ((i=0; i<${#input[@]}; i++)); do
   echo "Processing input=${input[$i]} and output=${output[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: Ahh thank you that makes more sense. Do you mind explaining what `((i=0; i<${#input[@]}; i++))` code means?

Comment: `((i=0; i<${#input[@]}; i++))` is iterating a variable `i` from `0` to the length of array `input`. `${#input[@]}` gives length of array.

Comment: @PythonNoob28: It it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

zsh enables multiple loop variables before the list.

```bash
#!/bin/zsh
input2output=(
    'File1' 'Outfile1'
    'File2' 'Outfile2'
)

for input ouput in $input2output
do
    echo "[$input] -->  [$ouput]"
done
```

quotes from [zsh(5.9) manual](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Complex-Commands) or `man zshmisc`

> for ***name*** ... [ in word ... ] term do list done
>
> ***More than one parameter name*** can appear before the list of words. If N names are given, then on each execution of the loop the next N words are assigned to the corresponding parameters. If there are more names than remaining words, the remaining parameters are each set to the empty string.